# KVM switch working on one computer but nor the other

Tags: switch, kvm-switch

I installed a IOGEAR KVM switch on two PC computers running windows 7.  One computer works fine, but when I switch to the other computer I can see the screen saver and nothing else.  The mouse and keyboard do not work and I can't see the desktop icons, drives etc.  I would really appreciate some help as my tech knowledge only goes so far.  Thank you.

Comment: I restarted the computer and now the mouse is working, but I still can't see the desktop and files.  All I see is the screen saver.

Answer (score 0):

How many ports does the KVM switch have?

Have you tried switching the non working machine to the port of the working machine?

If the KVM switch has more than two ports, have you tried any other ports?

Also, the model of the KVM switch would help.